# Main differences between elastodynamic and light scattering when using S-matrix to find bound states

Tags: mathematical-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, elasticity, s-matrix-theory

What are the main differences (top 5 if question is too broad), for using the S-matrix to find bound states, between elastodynamic and light scattering? (if it facilitates a higher quality question/answer, use cylinder of infinite length)